# How to get the custom page get_permalink?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, permalinks

I have create two a custom page called  `page-blogs.php` and `page-blog-content.php`.

In the `page-blogs.php` I am displaying my all the custom blogs post and `page-blog-content.php` will display the blog content.

I am usig below code to display the my all the blog post which is working and i am able to access my blog using this url `http://test.com/blogs/` but my issue is with `get_permalink($tid)`. When I am clickig on the my post the it's not redirecting on my `blog-content.php` page. It is rediecting on wordpress default post(I think single.php) and my URL is shwoing `http://test.com/blog/food-is-heavenly/`

```
$args = array(  
'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
'post_type' => 'blog',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 30,
'meta_key' => 'latestblog',
'meta_value' => 1,
'order'      => 'DESC' 
);  
$featured = new WP_Query($args);
$fdata ='';
$fddata = '<div class="main-Blog"><ul>';
while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured->the_post(); 
$tid = $featured->ID;


$fddata.=  '<li> <a href="'.get_permalink($tid).'">
<div class="main-blogBoxwrapper">
<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($tid).'">
<div class="blogCatname">
<h6><span>'.$catname.'</span></h6>
<h4>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title($tid), 14, '...').'</h4>
<p>'.wp_trim_words($get_the_content($tid), 20, '...').'</p>
</div>
</div>
</a></li>';
endwhile;
$fddata.='</ul></div>';

echo $fddata;
```

I know wordpress also providing the single post and content.php(template-part) but i am using this for my category and subcategory. I have different design for category and for blog post.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the question, and if you want to get the permalink of the current post/page, then you can use `get_the_ID()`, but call it before `new WP_Query()` call, or after calling `wp_reset_postdata()`. But as for linking to the `page-blog-content.php` page, what exactly do you mean? How is the single post permalink suppose to look like?

Comment: Also, as I said in my first (and deleted) comment, in the loop you should use `$tid = get_the_ID()` and not `$tid = $featured->ID`. And did you intentionally not using [template like `single-blog.php` in your case](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post)?

Comment: @SallyCJ, Give me some time to to do with template. I was using the custom page. Let me try with template. So I have to create blog and blog-content template.

Comment: @SallyCJ,  Apologize for the late reply, Actually, I have created a custom page called blogs.php where I am displaying my custom post blog data and when users click on the blog then I have to display the blog content on my blog-content.php page.

Comment: I used $tid = get_the_ID() instetd of  $tid = $featured->ID but othing is working.

Comment: Now I'm sorry for the late reply.. but you could actually just rename the `blog-content.php` template to `single-blog.php`, and when the single permalink is clicked, you'd see the content in the format you preferred.